# Проблема с выпадающим меню (CSS)

Tags: css, меню

Я новичок. Сейчас бьюсь над проектом. Не получается сделать выпадающее меню. Подскажите пожалуйста, что именно я делаю не так.
Вот код:
HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    <header class="header">
        <img class="logo" src="./images/logo.png" alt="Swarzmarkt">
        <button class="catalog">
            <div class="menu">
                <img class="catalog__catalog-pic" src="./images/catalog-menu.png">
                <p class="catalog__catalog-text"> Katalog</p>
            </div>
            <div class="catalog__catalog-content">
                <a href="#">Action 1</a> 
                <a href="#">Action 2</a>
                <a href="#">Action 3</a>
            </div>
        </button>
        
        <button class="catalog_catalog-all">
            <div class="menu">
                <p class="catalog__catalog-text">All </p>
                <img class="catalog__catalog-pic" src="./images/header-menu.png">
            </div>
            <div class="catalog__catalog-content">
                <a href="#">Action 1</a>
                <a href="#">Action 2</a>
                <a href="#">Action 3</a>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div class="search">
            <p class="search__search-text">Ich suche...</p>
            <img class="search__search-pic" src="./images/search.png">
        </div>
        <div class="rightsidebar">
            <a class="rightsidebar__rightsidebar-like" href="#"><img src="./images/like.png"></a>
            <a class="rightsidebar__rightsidebar-profile" href="#"><img src="./images/profile.png"></a>
            <a class="rightsidebar__rightsidebar-box" href="#"><img src="./images/box.png"></a>
        </div>
   </header>
</page>
```

```
CSS:
.page {
  min-width: 1100px;
  max-width: 1600px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #181818;
}

.header {
  /*height: 76px;*/
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  height: 63px;
  margin-left: 48px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.catalog {
  width: 121px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #181818;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.catalog__catalog-pic {
  width: 16.67px;
  height: 16.67px;
  margin-top: 13.76px;
  margin-bottom: 13.76px;
}

.catalog__catalog-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.catalog__catalog-text:hover {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.catalog_catalog-all {
  width: 96px;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.catalog__catalog-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 259px;
  height: 788px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.catalog__catalog-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.catalog__catalog-content a:hover {
  color: #e55e24;
}

.catalog:hover .catalog__catalog-content {
  display: block;
}

.catalog_catalog:hover .catalog__catalog-content {
  display: block;
}

.search {
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `overflow: hidden` у `.page` уберите. Указывайте конкретную проблему, а не "что я делаю не так"

Comment: Ясно. Хорошо. Большое спасибо!)